# Missing "return" at the end of the function Python

Tags: python, return

Quite a stupid question but...

```
def gcd(a, b):
    if a < b:
        a, b = b, a
    if a == 0:
        return b
    elif b == 0:
        return a
    return gcd(b, a % b)
```

So when there's no `return` at the end of the function, why would the code return `None`? When it's called recursively and `a` or `b` is eventually equal to `0`, it meets the `if` condition right? Then it should return the non-zero value.

Comment: The intermediate steps won't return a value then.

Comment: This function should never return `None`. What were the values of `a` and `b` that made you observe a `None`?

Comment: @DYZ The function as written above won't return None, but I think he's saying that when he omits the last return (making his last line simply `gcd(b, a % b)`) _then_ it returns `None`, and he's asking why.

Comment: @Dan Sounds like a plausible interpretation.

Answer (score 3):

If neither `a` nor `b` is equal to zero, neither one of the first two return statements will be executed.

Without the final return, the flow of control reaches the end of the function without hitting a return statement, so the [default value of `None`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) is returned.